# Java vps database connection Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, mysql, database, server, vps

I have created a Dynamic web application in Java, JSP and connected to MySQL server using phpMyAdmin as localhost database server. This is the code I have written in connection class:

```
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";
Statement stmt = null;
static Connection conn = null;
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbtest";

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

And while hosting this application on VPS (through Plesk parallel panel for Windows) I have changed the `DB_URL` to my server IP address:port and uploaded on server using .WAR file.

When I am trying to print conn object to check if the connection is establishing with database, I got the object value and connection was successful and all database operation are working well.

Comment: what does System.out do?